# What's wrong with my RewriteRule?

Tags: mod-rewrite

My .htaccess file currently looks like this

```
AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^account$ /account/orders.php [L]
```

When I go to `http://mywebsite.com/account` it properly shows the page at `http://mywebsite.com/account/orders.php`.  But when I change the RewriteRule to

```
RewriteRule ^account/orders$ /account/orders.php [L]
```

and then I go to `http://mywebsite.com/account/orders`, I get Error 404 Page Not Found.  What did I do wrong?

******Additional Details**

I finally diagnosed the problem.  But I don't understand why my solution works.  Consider the scenario where account/orders.php exists.

The following rule will not work

```
RewriteRule ^account/orders$ account/orders.php [L]
```

The following rule will work

```
RewriteRule ^account/order$ account/orders.php [L]
```

Ie., the rewrite rule will fail if the Pattern evaluates to an existing file.  So when the pattern is the same as the substitution, but minus the extension, the rewrite rule will fail.  If I add a file called account/order.php, then both rules will fail.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried a relative path?

```
RewriteRule ^account/orders$ account/orders.php [L]
```

---

**Edit**   You should also make sure to have [MultiViews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#multiviews) disabled. This causes that Apache does some additional vague file matching to find similar named files and thus `/account/orders` would be mapped to `/account/orders.php` before it’s passed to mod_rewrite.

Comment: I have tried relatives paths and absolute paths for both terms of the rewriterule. Still the same problem

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how your first example would work, because I believe that intial slashes are also passed on.

RewriteRule ^/account/orders$ /account/orders.php [L]

Answer (score 0):

Strange, it seems ok to me...
If you have access to Apache Configuration try to enable RewriteLog and RewriteLogLevel for some debug...

Also take a look in the site's log files (always if you have access)

Comment: sadly, I don't have access to apache configuration.  My shared hosting provider says I don't have access to apache server logs.  Are there other "types of logs" that I can check?

Comment: mmm i'm not pretty sure about this one, but maybe you can force an php script as default 404 page and do an print_r($_SERVER); inside it. In this mode you can see what exactly has been called and why apache doesn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

I would at first try to add a redirect to my rules, so I can see in the browser what is happening on the server.

```
RewriteRule ^account$ /account/orders.php [L,R]
```

Also make sure that there are no other rules (previous ones) interfering, just in case you are not showing all of your .htaccess file here.

Comment: yup, that's my entire .htaccess file, no other rules on it

Comment: RewriteRule ^account$ /account/orders.php [L,R] properly redirects, but the RewriteRule ^account/orders$ account/orders.php [L,R] redirects to a 404 page not found

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question because I finally diagnosed the problem. But I don't understand why my solution works. Consider the scenario where account/orders.php exists.

The following rule will not work

```
RewriteRule ^account/orders$ account/orders.php [L]
```

The following rule will work

```
RewriteRule ^account/order$ account/orders.php [L]
```

Ie., the rewrite rule will fail if the Pattern evaluates to an existing file. So when the pattern is the same as the substitution, but minus the extension, the rewrite rule will fail. If I add a file called account/order.php, then both rules will fail.

Why does this happen?